# how to display UIViewController from a NSObject class?

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, nsobject

There is a current view as `UIViewController` which call "LoginView" but I'm not in, I'm in a `NSObject` class and I want to call, display an other `UIViewController` which is call "MapView". How can I do this?[image]

The problem is like above screenshot.

Comment: Two things:  Why are you trying to instantiate and display a view controller from within a model, and [what have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[appDelegate loginViewController] presentViewController:mapViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
`
i tried that code but didn't work..

Comment: Is the name of your AppDelegate class really "AppDelegate"?
Moreover, there should be no need to present a viewController from an NSObject !

Comment: sure it's "AppDelegate".

Comment: I found true code fragment. may be somebody has same problem so i'm giving them.
`AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [[appDelegate window] addSubview:mapViewController.view];
 [[appDelegate window] bringSubviewToFront:mapViewController.view];`

Answer (score 10):

At your `IBAction` or specific method write this:

```
UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIViewController *root = [window rootViewController];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = root.storyboard;
CustomViewController *vcc =(CustomViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardID"];

[root presentModalViewController:vcc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you're trying to access your UIViewController member from a UIViewController class from a NSObject class. Easy just pass UIViewController member to the NSObject class. In this case a self. What that lets you do is you can change, edit, remove, whatever you want to do in your UIView from another class. The following is an example of that.

Calling the NSObject Class from your UIViewController class

```
@implementation myViewControllerClass

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    //Pass in the UIViewController object, in this case  itself. 
    [[myNSOBjectClass alloc] startViewController:self]; 
    ....
}
```

Then from your NSObject

```
@interface myNSOBjectClass{
    //Global access to the view controller. 
    UIViewController *viewController; 
}
...

@implementation myNSOBjectClass
...

//function that the caller calls to pass their UIViewController object 
- (void)startViewController:(UIViewController *)callerViewController{
    viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    //puts the caller's view controller to the global member.
    viewController = callerViewController;  
    ...
}
```

Now you have the view controller at your fingertips!

Cheers :)!

Comment: @Lifematch I had the same issue and I found this answer really useful

Answer (score 3):

I used like this in my NSObject class:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController presentViewController:yourMapViewContorller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I hope it's useful.

Comment: UIapplication.shared.delegate.window does not have rootViewController how you achieved it inside NSObject class?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be instantiating and displaying view controllers from within a model.  Views should be **driven** by models.

In this case you mentioned `LoginView` as your starting point.  When some condition is satisfied (successful login perhaps?) you should update the underlying model accordingly, and then display the `MapView`.

From within `LoginView`:

```
MapView *mapView = [[MapView alloc] init];
```

If your app uses a navigation controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapView animated:YES];
```

Otherwise:

```
[self presentViewController:mapView animated:YES completion:<nil or block>];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code. It'll help to you......

In your button click action You have to send your UINavigationController & current ViewController. Because NSObject class not found that controller.

In your Button Action put this Code:

```
[demo login_method_called:self.navigationController withCurrentViewController:self];
```

In your NSObject .h class put this code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Home_ViewController.h"

@interface Method_Action_class : NSObject

- (void)login_method_called:(UINavigationController*)navigation  withCurrentViewController:(UIViewController*) controller;
@end
```

In your NSObject .m class put this code:

```
#import "Method_Action_class.h"

@implementation Method_Action_class

-(void)login_method_called:(UINavigationController*)navigation  withCurrentViewController:(UIViewController*) controller
{
    Home_ViewController *home = [[Home_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home_ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [navigation pushViewController:home animated:YES];
}
@end
```

And Build your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an obersver in view controller class and declare a method of push view controller and post notification using NSNotification centre from NSObject subclass and it is working well.

in view controller:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissPickerView) name:kNotificationDismissPicker object:nil];

in subclass of NSOject: 
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kMoveToAchievementView object:nil];